# How is it possible for a Mutex to be constructed at compile time?

Tags: rust, mutex, compile-time

It is [now possible](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/66806) to compile the following code:

```
use std::sync::Mutex;

static GUARD: Mutex<()> = Mutex::new();
```

I am trying to understand how this is possible.

My understanding of `const` functionality in Rust is that there is a subset of the language that is available to you at compile time. The classic example being that `1+1` can be calculated at compile time, so why wait until runtime to pay the cost of the addition. Accepting this, then if you have a function like

```
const fn two() -> u32 {
   1+1
}
```

and it is called somewhere, then again the compiler should do this up front, inline the value and save the function call. The subset of const-callable code is growing over time, but there is obviously a hard limit on this of any operations requiring runtime input.

A `Mutex` strikes me as something requiring runtime input. It relies on operating system specific system calls to allow synchronisation to occur between threads. Although the compiler knows which OS it is targeting, I don't see how this initialisation can happen at compile time without requiring something at runtime at all.

Comment: When you think about `const` initialization, you really only need to think about data, not behavior. What data does a mutex need? Some space for whatever `T` you're putting inside it, and an atomic number to tell you what state it's in (and a poison flag but whatever). _Creating_ a mutex doesn't require any runtime-dependent computations. _Using it_ does. That's why e.g. `lock` isn't `const`.

Comment: @isaactfa: That's... an answer, actually.

Comment: Thanks @isaactfa. Following your logic through then - the obvious question 'how can an atomic number be initialized const' can be answered in the same manner: an atomic number is implemented I suppose just as a number, but where accesses use specific access patterns with syscalls or something to prevent unsafe access.

Comment: @user17506014 Atomic operations aren't system calls, but special set of CPU instructions. Other than that, you are right.

Comment: Even if atomic ops were system calls, during initialization, the new function has exclusive access to the memory its initializing, so there's no need for atomic access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On modern operating systems, mutexes are not special OS-level objects - they're just memory regions accessed by atomic operations (which are CPU instructions) in a way that guarentees exclusive access.

The only time that the OS enters the picture is when dealing with waiting. Threads trying to access a locked mutex need to tell the OS to block and schedule other tasks, and threads releasing a mutex may need to tell the OS to wake up the waiting threads.

So for initializing a mutex, the OS doesn't need to be involved. You don't even need atomic operations, as the initializer has exclusive access.

For Linux, this is done through the [`futex` system call](https://man.archlinux.org/man/futex.2). The two basic operations of it are to atomically check a memory address and wait, or to wake up any other threads waiting on a memory address - neither of which involve a file descriptor or any other OS-level object.